# Looking for something to generate and draw Graphs

Tags: ubuntu, latex, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a software to create vector images of Graphs. below features are required:

- Be able to draw special graphs like n-complete , K graphs etc.
- Available for ubuntu

I want to generate ps-tricks code (if possible). there should be something like LaTeX-Draw specialized in graphs. is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dot2tex`](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) to translate [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) files in PSTricks or PGF/TikZ commands. You can even write directly in the LaTeX source code with the [dot2texi](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/dot2texi.html) package, [here](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/documentation/#the-dot2texi-latex-package)'s an example.

Anyway [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) itself is able to produce several formats (ps, svg, etc.).

All you have to do is learn the [DOT language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) syntax (used by [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)), but there are plenty of [examples](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) around.

I'm not sure if this fits with you special needs, but maybe it's worth to make a try.

Comment: it looks to be useful. at least it's more easier than using pstricks. thanx :)