# How to embed Graphviz in LyX?

Tags: latex, lyx, graphviz

I want to embed `dot` scripts within `.lyx` files, I added the following line:

```
(In document LaTeX preamble: )
\usepackage{graphviz}
```

however, latex errored:

```
LaTeX Error: File `graphviz.sty' not found.
```

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lyx should know .dot files itself when graphviz is correctly installed. no need for preamble hacking, just insert it as a normal picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you don't have the `graphviz.sty` package correctly installed. Maybe [this](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/03/25/embedding-graphviz-in-latex-documents) can help you. Anyway there are other ways to embed `Graphviz` in LaTeX, see a [previuos answer](https://superuser.com/questions/192048/looking-for-something-to-generate-and-draw-graphs/192111#192111) of mine.